# Decision table in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Given a data frame and a set of rules defined in a table.

```
df <- rbind(c("blue","M",9),c("blue","F",11))
colnames(df)<-c("eyes","gender","age")

rule <- rbind(c("blue","M","<10",1),c("blue","M",">10",2),c("blue","F","<10",3),c("blue","F",">10",4))
colnames(rule)<-c("eyes","gender","age","category" )
```

Is there a way in R to apply the rules without rewriting the if else script?

The result should look like this:

```
 eyes   gender age  category
"blue"   "M"     9    1
"blue"   "F"     11   4
```

Comment: How different can these rules be in the general case?

Comment: they can only be checked for logical expression =,<,>,=<,>=,  between. There could be an infinite number of condition columns but a single result.

Comment: Sounds good, except perhaps "between"; would it be, e.g., "between 10 and 14"? Or just two columns?

Comment: yes between 2 values

Answer (score 4):

```
require(magrittr); require(dplyr)
# Convert to data.frame
rule %<>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
df %<>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)

#left join on eyes and gender, then remove rows where age doesn't match

result <- df %>% 
            left_join(rule, by = c('eyes', 'gender'))%>% 
            filter(paste(age.x, age.y) %>% sapply(function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))) %>% 
            select(-age.y)
```